# Populate Formatted dates form select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Hi Stackoverflow Community.

On my application I have select option where a user selects a date option and based on that option I populate the dates accordingly.

However the date or week must start on a Sunday and end on a Saturday.
For the months selection it always start from the first.
Current month will count all of August, Next 2 months will start from Sept to end of Oct.

Here is what I wrote so far

### [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/tuxobaxacade/1/edit/)

If you have a

```
 Moments JS
```

solution I would also welcome it

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've always like to learn about the vagaries of js Date(), so I put together this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/dk9qpckk/5/).

It uses standard js data manipulation through a series of functions that you'll be able to figure out fairly easily.

What I'm not sure of is what you mean by "month" "two months" and "six months" - I've assumed that a month is a four week period, and not a calendar month.

edit: I re-read your text and I'll work on the definition of month.

Here are the JS functions:

```
function adddays(anydate1, daystoadd)
{
  var mydaystoadd = daystoadd;
  var daysadded = anydate1.getDate() + mydaystoadd;
  return new Date( anydate1.setDate( daysadded ) );
}

function startofweek( anydate )
{
  localdate = anydate;
  daydifference = 0;
  daydifference = localdate.getDate() - numericdayofweek( localdate );
  return new Date( localdate.setDate( daydifference ) );  
}

function textdayofweek(mydate)
{
  var dayarray = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  return dayarray[ numericdayofweek(mydate) ];
}

function numericdayofweek( anydate7 )
{
  var localdate = anydate7;
  return localdate.getDay();
}

function todayfull() 
{
  return new Date();
}

function todayshort( mydate3 )
{
 localdate = mydate3;
 thedate =
 (localdate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + 
  localdate.getDate() + '/' + 
  localdate.getFullYear();
  return thedate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @TimSPQR I appreciate your answer I will use it.

Comment: I also found a way of doing it using moment.js take a look at this link

http://jsbin.com/gosahuwadino/4/